# use mapview as background for multiple screens

Tags: ios, user-interface, android-mapview

I'd like to be able to use a map view as a unified background for my app.
So different views would be overlaid on that map view.
Transitions from one view to another would ideally only affect the views on top of the map. Not the map it's self.

Has anyone tackled this before and maybe know the best course of action for achieving it?

Other than load times for the map are there any hard reasons why it might be a poor UI Design?

Thanks

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Container View Controllers to achieve this effect. Take a look at apple docs for that.  Basically you're root view would be the map view, and the "contained" views would be overlaid.

Hope this helps,

Cam